# GraphQL Rails: Should I define`authorized?` as an instance or class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I have a rails 6 API using graphql (2.0) gem.

I'm very confused about the use of `authorized`. Sometimes I see it defined as an instance method and sometimes prefixed with `self`.

Examples in queries:

```rb
module Queries
  module Admin
    class DraftProviders < BaseQuery
      type [Types::ProviderType], null: true

      def resolve
        ::Provider.draft.order(created_at: :desc)
      end

      def self.authorized?(object, context)
        context[:current_user]&.has_role?(:admin)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
module Queries
  module Registration
    class CalculateRegistrationPrice < BaseQuery
      argument :registration_attributes, Types::Inputs::DraftRegistrationInput, required: true

      type Types::RegistrationPriceBreakdown, null: true
      description 'Validate and get a breakdown of the amount to pay before registering to a class'

      def resolve(registration_attributes:)
        # ...stuff
      end

      def authorized?(registration_attributes:)
        learner = registration_attributes.learner
        registration = learner.registrations.build(schedule: registration_attributes.schedule)

        super && current_user && allowed_to?(:manage?, registration)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**When should I use which? What are the pros/cons?**
[The documentation](https://graphql-ruby.org/authorization/authorization.html) does not clarify things for me since it doesn't mention Queries and Mutations.

Not sure if it matter but I'm using `action_policy-graphql` gem for authorization.